# How does Software Defined Perimeter (SDP) protect against certains attack that happen in the browser?

Tags: network, xss, csrf, network-access-control

I have been doing a bit of research on SDP (Software Defined Perimeter) but it's still a bit unclear to me how it protects against certain types of attacks.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Defined_Perimeter) it says that it can protect against these attacks:

- cross-site scripting (XSS)
- cross-site request forgery (CSRF)

And many others. But I am just wandering for these two.

If I understand SDP correctly it's a way to controller specific access to specific services/servers/etc for a user.

So how does it help against XSS and CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 1):

SDP is a closed VPN solution replacing traditional VPN services like (MPLS, VPN concentrator, etc). The typical enterprise use case eliminates below pain points:

- Leave their applications open to the Internet
- Create an in-office VPN concentrator
- Implement basic firewalling
- Build their own VPN gateways
- Pursue a traditional corporate VPN service

You may refer a commercial SDP solution at: https://www.perimeter81.com/software-defined-perimeter-enterprise

In my opinion, claim of getting rid of DDoS, XSS and CSRF are coming form the nature of not opening Enterprise applications to internet (users can connect through SDP with proper controls).

But this may not be applicable for services offered through internet (like eCommerce).

Comment: So the user is not accessing the rest of the Internet at the same time? How can an SDP stop a user from clicking on a link in a malicious email or rather recognize that the link being open by the user was an accident (so a CSRF)? It has it's own browser? I am still unsure about that part (the same for XSS). Those attacks don't seem preventable unless you modify the code of the applications themselves to prevent CSRF and XSS.

Comment: There are no single control can protect from threats. It's always recommended to have multiple controls to mitigate risks...

Answer (score 0):

> So how does it help against XSS and CSRF attacks?

They generally don't. Not every product with SDP on the label will do that.

This looks more like a capability for a Next-Generation Firewall that can decrypt traffic, inspect content, and detect XSS/CSRF problems (assumed to be threats or attacks).

Furthermore, a Web Application Firewall is also a component that would sit between an existing web application and the internet. It could conceivably detect XSS/CSRF attacks, but not with 100% reliability. The web browser is the thing that needs to protect against this, and the web server needs to assert the correct policy in HTTP headers.

This is likely an overreach in the Wikipedia article that needs to be corrected. Such statements dilute what SDP is actually about.